# Method '' cannot handle event'

Tags: vb.net

> Method 'RadioButton1_CheckedChanged' cannot handle event 'Checked'Changed' because they do not have a compatible signature.

The text above is the error I'm facing, and below is the code.

It's the same with RadioButton2

```
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(ByVal e As System.EventArgs, ByVal sender As System.Object) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    FlatButton4.Enabled = False
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Double click on a new RadioButton in the designer, and it will generate this `Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged`. Literally all you need to do.

Comment: I've tried that, but it's the same error. Though when i remove <code>, e As EventArgs</code>

Comment: Try deleting the sub entirely, go to the form design tab and double click on the radio button. This should generate the proper event handler with the correct signatures. Then add your code back into the sub.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong order of parameters. The *signature* is the list of parameters between the () of the method.

```
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
  FlatButton4.Enabled = False
  Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: That should work perfectly. Did you change the order of parameters?